# Prospective Jews and Shabbat observance

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, gentiles, reform-judaism

Can someone who is not Jewish but is seriously considering converting observe Shabbat? Here I specifically mean home observance (Kiddush, etc.). Also, can a non-Jew looking into converting pray Jewish prayers? I'm coming from a Reform viewpoint if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

In either January of 1984 or April of 1983 (I can't tell because of the format of the book online) the Reform Movement published a [responsum (#165)](https://books.google.com/books?id=6YbKqlxCZdsC&pg=PA247#v=onepage&q&f=false) about whether a non-Jew may light Shabbat candles.  In the responsum, they state that while it is technically problematic for a non-Jew to say the blessing which includes "... who sanctified *us* with his commandments," doing so is seen as a "positive indication that the home is to be Jewish."

> The non-Jewish spouse's participation in the Friday evening ritual at home has evolved naturally. Frequently she does light the *shabbat* candles and through this indicates a wish to establish some ties with Judaism at home. Technically, of course, it is inappropriate for a Christian to recite the traditional benediction as it contains the words *asher qidshanu* - "who sanctified us with his commandments," which indicates an obligation imposed on Jews. We have, however, taken this act as a positive indication that the home is to be Jewish.

The responsum goes on to say that the same logic cannot be extended to synagogue services. "[N]on-Jews may not lead in essential segments of the synagogue service or sections which utilize such phrases as 'who has sanctified us.'"

Since your question indicates that you are specifically asking about home observances, I think it is can be understood that from the position of the Reform movement you may participate as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You may certainly do the prayers and make the kiddush.

It would be best if you're still doing *something* that's not Sabbath-observant at some point in the day. (E.g. drive a car, or light a fire.)

Good luck with your journey! At some point you should be able to determine if you want to go all the way to conversion, or if not, then Shabbat is not for you. (But feel free to borrow freely from Jewish prayer texts if it suits you.)

Comment: Source that a non-Jew should make blessings (i.e. kiddush) with Hashem's name?

Answer (score -4):

In Reform Judaism, you don't need to not observe Shabbat. Do what you think is most meaningful to you. If you don't intend to become orthodox, there's not really a restriction on Shabbat.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, the answers says "you don't need to **not** observe Shabbat" (emphasis supplied). This seems to answer the question AFAICT -- though of course it's a weak answer, as it's unsourced.

Comment: @msh210 whoops, I did indeed miss that "not".  I'm sorry OldBunny2800; I'll undelete.  But please consider msh210's comment; this would benefit from a source.  Thanks.

Comment: @msh210 Does this not fail Isaac's test here http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/472/759 ?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think msh210 was interpreting the answer according to the first sentence which says "you don't need to **not** observe Shabbat."  This is, of course, in contradiction with the last sentence.

Comment: @DoubleAA, yeah, I guess it does.

Comment: @DoubleAA good point.  I think this is a poor answer (both unsourced and incorrect), and I've voted accordingly.  If others think it's also not an answer (per our guidelines) I'd go along with that.

Comment: @Monica `I'm coming from a reform viewpoint if that makes a difference.` I think my answer is definitely relevant to the question and correct.

Comment: @Daniel, since you're pingable, what do you think? (See the Meta post that Double AA linked to, and the remainder of this comment.) ¶ 
OldBunny2800, see the Meta post that Double AA linked to: we "maintain a standard underlying point of view for all content on the site that Jewish law and tradition are, in fact, binding". If you want to claim that Reform Judaism says this law isn't binding then you should be able to back that up with citations to (presumably Reform) authorities that discuss this specific law. [continued]

Comment: [continued] Otherwise, this answer does not seem to represent Judaism -- not even Reform Judaism. See especially the lashon-hara example in that Meta post.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 as one counterexample to your reasoning, most Reform rabbis will not allow non-Jews to say the "mitzvah b'rachot", like the the *aliyah* blessings, even for a family member's bar mitzvah.  So there are clearly some boundaries to the "anything goes; do what you find meaningful" approach you're describing.  Also, it is incorrect to assume that no Reform Jew cares about *halacha*.

Comment: @msh210 I'm torn because the question _does_ specifically mention that it's being asked from the POV of Reform Judaism. If it is true that Reform Judaism doesn't consider halacha to be binding then perhaps that part of the question takes the entire question out of scope for the site. If, on the other hand, Reform Judaism does consider halacha to be binding, then perhaps it's irrelevant to the question? So maybe we should just remove that point? There is also the third possibility that Reform Judaism does believe that there is some halacha in this case that ought to be followed, but that

Comment: halacha is different from what other streams of Judaism hold.

Comment: @Daniel, according to Monica Cellio's last comment, just above, Reform Judaism does keep certain _halachos_. (I doubt that it considers binding all the _halachos_ that traditional Judaism considers binding. So I think it makes sense to include in the question "I'm coming from a Reform viewpoint".) That is, I think your third possibility is true. But this answer seems to reject _halacha_ altogether. See the _lashon-hara_ example in [the Meta post](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/472).

Comment: @msh210 I agree that this answer doesn't really address the question as asked (the question is about potential Jews and the answer is about Jews themselves) but suppose the answer is "Reform Judaism doesn't care whether non-Jews keep Shabbat" because they hold relevant halachot to not be binding. Does that mean that there's no way to answer the question within the rules of the site?

Comment: @msh210 In other words, can a question be rendered off-topic because of its answer?

Comment: @Daniel, it seems false that Reform Judaism holds all _halacha_ to be nonbinding. If it holds *this* _halacha_ to be nonbinding, then there should be some documentation of that fact somewhere.

Comment: @Daniel, @msh210 Reform Judaism allows members to pick and choose the halachic rules they wish to follow, hence my answer `you don't need to observe Shabbat` and `Do what is most meaningful to you`

Comment: @msh210 So if it turns out to be the case that Reform Judaism holds this halacha to be non-binding, is that an acceptable answer in light of the meta post linked above?

Comment: @Daniel Sounds like it to me. An answer that claimed that should (like any answer) substantiate its claim. **This** answer, however, seems to be saying that **all** _halacha_ is nonbinding according to Reform Judaism, which is why I think it doesn't pass the test set forth in that Meta post and should be deleted.

Comment: OldBunny2800, just so you know, you can't ping two people in a single comment. If you can support that claim from a Reform source, then by all means edit the claim into your post. Pinging @MonicaCellio to see the above comments.

Comment: OldBunny2800 if you can prove that's what the reform movement believes, that would make this a better answer. See my answer above where I quote a responsum of the reform movement.